# Is it an anti pattern to have two UI input element for the same value?

Tags: input, anti-patterns

Does having two different UI elements for the same input value considered an anti pattern? Both inputs represent the same thing, changing the value of one will update the other.

For example, I wanted to have a slider that the user can select a numeric value from, and a dropdown that displays the value and make it also possible to change it.

[image: slider with linked dropdown]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No, it is not an anti-pattern as long as it is obvious to the user that both indicators can change the control.** In many cases, having more than one way to manipulate a control can be considered a way to improve accessibility. For example, a slider that provides an open text field improves keyboard control.

From [Designing the Perfect Slider](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2017/07/designing-perfect-slider/):

> To provide a shortcut to precise input with a slider, we can use
> either predefined presets — frequently chosen values or value ranges —
> or enhance the slider with a **text input field fallback**. Both presets
> and the input field could be progressively disclosed — either by a tap
> on a button or just from a tap on the current value on the slider.

This example allows the user to input text, manipulate with a slider, and manipulate with plus and minus step controls.

[image: A slider with a text input field]

Answer (score 0):

It's not an anti-pattern , it is quite occurring, yet some cosmetical changes would make it more usable, like showing what the smallest and highest value is, even median value if there is a big range and the dropdown should sit either on top or bottom right or maybe centered ( the values can be skipped if the range is small ). Not sure if a dropdown makes sense and it depends on your use case. Usually a field aiding a slider serves the purpose of allowing the user to select an exact value like 213 by entering it in the field.

Answer (score 0):

Its not anti-pattern & is in fact perfectly appropriate in some cases

Obviously depends on context which I don't have, but a numeric input box might make more sense than a dropdown, especially if the range of values is huge & the input requires precision.